# Raspberry Pi 3 not responding

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Today, I have a RPI3 which is under Rasbian.
Power wire are on 2.5A and temperature are around 39/40°C (I had a fan on it)

My problem is: My Raspberry Pi 3 is connected to my box and it's use as a web server. For now it works "perfectly". But sometimes - and this is the problem - the Pi is not responding.

I mean that all my website are "offline", I can't connect via via SSH locally and the only thing I need to do is to "force" reboot it by remove the wire.
After that everything is OK.

Actually, I don't know where to look for. It's can't be hardware issue because of the wire and the temp right ?

So is it a software issue? If yes, How can I know which froze the device ?

Comment: Do you mean that the Pi us drawing a 2.5A supply current? That's an awful lot for a Pi. Are you monitoring CPU load, etc? Even under 100% CPU conditions, the Pi rarely draws more than 750mA. Do you have peripherals connected that draw additional current? Can your power supply actually cope with 2.5W?

Comment: you say you have a fan on it. since they're perfectly capable of running without one (and cooling passively), am i to glean from this that you have overclocked it to a ludicrous level? if so, that is possibly why it's occasionally crashing

Comment: @KevinBoone Yes I have a 2.5A power supply. I also tried a 1A PS... Same. No USB periph or other periph except the LAN wire of course. ;)

Comment: @TimothyGroote I didn't overclock it haha. I had a fan on it because of the case I buyed. :p

Comment: If my Pi was drawing 2.5A, and I wasn't over-clocking it, and I had no peripherals attached to it, I would assume that either (a) it's defective or (b) my ammeter is defective. Under light load a Pi typically draws 300-400mA; under heavy load 500mA or so. I've never know a healthy, unmodified one to draw more than 1A. I suggest something might be broken. Seriously -- it could be a fire hazard :/

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plug in a monitor and look what happened. Maybe you see a kernel panic or kernel oops on the screen, maybe you can just login on the terminal and look what happened (maybe the network is down for some reason).

If everything freezes without visible error on the console, add more logging. install a munin, use verbose logging for all services you're using and read the logs after the freeze and look at the munin graphs what happened (i.e. if there is a memleak, you probably see it in the memory graph before everything freezes).

Comment: Thanks, I will check for munin. Actually, HTOP give me this: https://forum.yunohost.org/uploads/default/original/1X/12270cc1f631b1ad052d4b7ef4d71d9220b6e865.jpg

Comment: With Munin, I saw that a defective install of Docker was here... Removed it and it seems to be good. Wait and see.

Answer (score 1):

Using dmesg would not work after you reboot, so maybe you can find a software-related error in /var/log/kern.log. Since raspbian is based on debian, I would expect to find kernel logs here.

I would add this as a comment, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: No problem :) Here is the kern.log https://zerobin.net/?9eb17b8f67fc9729#QwgfvEd6ELiokikknBKWHwW6PXDz4xLX2q8elDfR7tU=

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on ubuntu while running a docker container as a daemon on raspberry pi 3. At first glance everything was running without a problem, but from time to time, the container stopped working and i could not connect via ssh.

In my case a reinstallation of the os solved the problem. But i have to add, that i used a different sd card for the new installation.
I think the root cause of the problem was, that i switched of the power on the first boot because i coulnd't connect via ssh right away and that probabaly caused the defect.